# How to check size of the files in a directory with python?

Tags: python, size, compare

I have a folder that contains 4 text files. I want to program a code with which I would be able to check the size of the files in my folder and only open those that has equal sizes. Anyone has any idea?

I have already tried this

```
import os


d=os.stat('H:/My Documents/211').st_size
```

Comment: It's good that you've tried something. Presumably it didn't do what you wanted. What did it do? What did you expect it to do?

Comment: the result of the printing d shows a zero to me. I want to compare the size of the files and open those that has equal sizes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get all of the files in a directory, you can use `os.listdir`.

```
>>> import os
>>> basedir = 'tmp/example'
>>> names = os.listdir(basedir)
>>> names
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Then you need to add `basedir` on to the names:

```
>>> paths = [os.path.join(basedir, name) for name in names]
>>> paths
['tmp/example/a', 'tmp/example/b', 'tmp/example/c']
```

Then you can turn that into a list of pairs of (name, size) using a os.stat(path).st_size (the example files I've created are empty):

```
>>> sizes = [(path, os.stat(path).st_size) for path in paths]
>>> sizes
[('tmp/example/a', 0), ('tmp/example/b', 0), ('tmp/example/c', 0)]
```

Then you can group the paths with the same size together by using a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
>>> import collections
>>> grouped = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for path, size in sizes:
...     grouped[size].append(path)
... 
>>> grouped
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: ['tmp/example/a', 'tmp/example/b', 'tmp/example/c']})
```

Now you can get all of the files by size, and open them all (don't forget to close them afterwards!):

```
>>> open_files = [open(path) for path in grouped[0]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can I put the grouped items in a list and write it to csv file so can be accessible for later use?

Comment: That depends on what you want in the CSV file. Rows with size,filename1,filename2,filename3?

Answer (score 9):

I can't reproduce your error. This

```
import os
print os.path.getsize('mydata.csv')
print os.stat('mydata.csv').st_size
```

Yields

```
359415
359415
```

I'm guessing that the filename you provide is wrong. This will print the size of all files in a folder

```
my_dir = r'path/to/subdir/'

for f in os.listdir(my_dir):
    path = os.path.join(my_dir, f)
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        print os.path.getsize(path)
```

Comment: Thank you the second one worked for me. And do you have any idea how can I code so that files with equal sizes be opened?